# How to find hash of a database resultset in php

Tags: php, mysql, hash, resultset

I can find the hash of a result set after retrieving it and storing in array using following method.

```
while( $records[] = mysqli_fetch_array($rs) ) {} 
md5( json_encode($records) )
```

Is there any other faster way to find hash of mysql result ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using hash when fetch data from db

like this.

`SELECT MD5(concat(field1, field2, field3, ...)) AS rowhash`